# Flask-SQLAlchemy and modify the join

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Hello I am trying to modify the join clause, since when it automatically join. It joins the wrong clause.

```
JOIN schedule ON schedule.course_id  = course.course_id
```

instead of

```
JOIN schedule ON schedule.schedule_id = task.schedule_id
```

Here is how my ORM query looks like:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import and_

myclases = (1, 2, 3)
    mytask = db.session.query(
        Task.task_id,
        Task.task_name,
        Course.course_name,
        Schedule.schedule_day,
        Schedule.schedule_week,
        Schedule.schedule_year,
        Module.module_timestamp
        ).join(
            Course,
            and_(Schedule.schedule_id == Task.schedule_id), #this line
            Module
            ).filter(Task.class_id.in_(myclases))
```

I have **marked** the line with a comment. To show where I am struggling.

I read that if you wanted to modify a join clause you have to use `and_`. But if I do so I am getting this error: 
 `AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'selectable'`

Is there any other way to modify the join?

**edit** - *added models*

```
class Task(db.Model):
    task_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    task_name = db.Column(db.String(64))

    course_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('course.course_id'))
    class_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('class.class_id'))
    schedule_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('schedule.schedule_id'))


class Course(db.Model):
    course_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    course_name = db.Column(db.String(64))

    schedule = db.relationship('Schedule', backref='course')
    task = db.relationship('Task', backref='course')
    mm_children_class_course = db.relationship('Class', secondary=class_course_identifier, backref=db.backref('courses'))
    mm_children_teacher_course = db.relationship('User', secondary=teacher_course_identifier)


class Schedule(db.Model):
    schedule_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    schedule_week = db.Column(db.Integer)
    schedule_day = db.Column(db.Integer)
    schedule_year = db.Column(db.Integer)

    course_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('course.course_id'))
    class_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('class.class_id'))
    module_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('module.module_id'))
    task = db.relationship('Task', backref='schedule')


class Module(db.Model):
    module_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    module_name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    module_timestamp = db.Column(db.Integer)
    module_endtime = db.Column(db.Integer)
    schedule = db.relationship('Schedule', backref='module')


class_course_identifier = db.Table('class_course_identifier',
    db.Column('course_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('course.course_id')),
    db.Column('class_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('class.class_id'))
)
```

**perhaps a solution**
I have maybe found a soft solution for this, instead of modifying the join I have added a filter.

```
db.session.query(
    Task.task_id,
    Task.task_name,
    Course.course_name,
    Schedule.schedule_day,
    Schedule.schedule_week,
    Schedule.schedule_year,
    Module.module_timestamp
).join(
    Course,
    Schedule,
    Module
).filter(
    Schedule.schedule_id == Task.schedule_id, # the added filter
    Task.class_id.in_(myclases)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work since the and_ should act on two arguments (at least, can be more). This is failing since you only have one argument. Please post your models and a link to the docs where you read about using the and_ function for further help..

Comment: Hello, I read it somewhere here on Stackoverflow, but can't recall what the link was called (read it on mobile). But I have added some of my models, feel free to ask for more! So far I have found a soft solution for this, look at the button of my post.

Answer (score 0):

I get that exactly worded error if I make this syntax typo

```
...
q = q.join(Foo.id == Bar.id)
...
```

instead of

```
...
q = q.join(Foo,Foo.id == Bar.id)
...
```

Maybe that is helpful to you